# pyzmq import error on Poll.pyd

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm trying to import ZMQ for the first time and im running into the following error. I broke the init imports into singular lines to see where the error was coming from specifically. It seems poll.pyd is failing for some reason.  It could be my environment here at work as this does not seem to happen at home. Any thoughts on how to dig into this?

> ```
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
> File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\zmq\tests\test_zmqstream.py", line 31, in <module>
>   import zmq
> File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
>   from zmq import core, devices
> File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\zmq\core\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
>   from zmq.core import poll
> ```

Running zmq with this installer:
pyzmq-2.1.4.win32-py2.6.msi

Comment: Have you tried with a relatively current installer?  [these](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq) are kept up to date, if you are stuck on Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `pyzmq-2.1.4.win32-py2.6.msi` you will have the `zmq` and `pyzmq` eggs in your `lib/site-packages`. Copy the `zmq` and `pyzmq` eggs to your `python26/lib/site-package/` directory, then run your python.

So , when you install `pyzmq-2.1.4.win32-py2.6.msi` you will get `pyzmq-2.1.4-py2.6.egg-info` and `zmq`. Keep these two into your installed python, inside this path: `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`.